# Nativescript RadSideDrawer gives symbol not available at run time error

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am following nativescript RadSideDrawer doc at:
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/SideDrawer/getting-started, but once I started the app in ios emulator, I am getting this error:

```
CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/./bundles/core.umd.js:1052:24: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Metadata for "TelerikUI.TKSideDrawerView" found but symbol not available at runtime.

RadSideDrawer@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/sidedrawer.js:15:38
```

I tried several times and always got the same error.

What's wrong with this? Is the documentation having errors here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there may be inconsistency and incompatibility in the used dependencies in your package.json. You can take a look at the sdkAngular repository that showcases many scenarios for using the RadSideDrawer and the other components of the nativescript-telerik-ui-pro plugin [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular).

Other things that you can try is to clean the project, by deleting the platforms and node_modules folders and running `tns run ios` after that.